# How to access some constant value in C from Python3 with ctypes

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

How to access pre-defined constant value from python with ctypes?

I have tried get a value, for example SIGTERM (it is clear that value be 15 in my environment x64 linux.) with ctypes.
Following is code that I wrote, but it raise a ValueError (Undefined Symbol).
Why this error caused?

Note that I using Ubuntu 19.10, x64, Python 3.7.5

code:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import *
libc_path = find_library("c")
libc = CDLL(libc_path)
sigterm_value = c_int.in_dll(libc, "SIGTERM")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because *SIGTERM* ([[man7]: SIGNAL(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) is a **macro** (`#define`: [[GNU.GCC]: Object-like Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros)) rather than a constant. 
As a consequence, **it doesn't reside in *libc*** (meaning that you can't get it via *CTypes*), but it's just an alias (if you will), that is being replaced by the preprocessor to its value everywhere in (*C*) source code before compiling.

According to the (official) source file ([[SourceWare]: [glibc.git]/bits/signum-generic.h](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=bits/signum-generic.h)):

```c
#define SIGTERM     15  /* Termination request.  */
```

In *Ubtu 16 64bit* (I know it's old, but it's the only *Nix* *VM* running at this point), it ends up being defined in */usr/include/bits/signum.h*:

```c
#define SIGTERM         15      /* Termination (ANSI).  */
```

You should use [[Python 3.Docs]: signal - Set handlers for asynchronous events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html):

> ```py
> >>> import signal
> >>> signal.SIGTERM
> <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>
> >>> signal.SIGTERM.value
> 15
> ```